# Using Composer Dataflow operator to pass classpath jar with main jar

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to orchestrate a dataflow job using composer dataflow Operator. My dataflow jar needs two additional jar which cannot be added as maven dependency.
Currently, I am running my job manually with below command:

> **java -cp Mainprocess.jar com.sample.class com.auth.dependency --tmp --staging**

When I am running this in cloud shell I have dependency jar in PWD.
Is it possible to pass the other classpath jars with Dataflow Operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Dataflow stages all files in the CLASSPATH.

You can override this by specifying the [filesToStage](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L187) pipeline option and manually specifying the set of jars that should be staged.

Comment: Thanks. I thought using the same but I had one doubt, Do I need to provide all the maven dependency jars along with these two jars coz I am overriding filesToStage ?